# Heroku release section overrides release process

Tags: django, docker, heroku, yaml, docker-container

I have the following `heroku.yml` file for containers deployment:

```
build:
  docker:
    release:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: release_image
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    PROD: "True"
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py migrate users && python manage.py migrate
run:
  # web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
  web: daphne config.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
  celery:
    command:
      - celery --app=my_app worker --pool=prefork --concurrency=4 --statedb=celery/worker.state -l info
    image: web
  celery_beat:
    command:
      - celery --app=my_app beat -l info
    image: web
```

When I deploy I get the following warning, which does not make any sense to me:

`Warning: You have declared both a release process type and a release section. Your release process type will be overridden.`

My `Dockerfile` is composed of two stages and I want to keep only the `release_image` stage:

```
FROM python:3.8 as builder
...
FROM python:3.8-slim as release_image
...
```

According to the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#targeting-a-stage-from-a-multi-stage-build) the proper way to choose `release_image` is to use the `target` section within `build` step.
But it also [mentions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#release-configuring-release-phase) that I can run my migrations within a `release` section.

**So what am I supposed to do to get rid of this warning?** I could only live with it if it was clear that both my `migrations` and `target` are being considered during deploy.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to keep only the `release_image` stage

Assuming this is true for your `web` process as well, update your `build` section accordingly:

```
build:
  docker:
    web:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: release_image
  config:
    PROD: "True"
```

Now you only have one process type defined and it targets the build stage you want to use.

Since you can run your migrations from the `web` container there's no need to build a whole container just for your Heroku `release` process. (And since your `release` section uses the `web` image the `release` process defined in `build` wouldn't have been for anything used anyway.)

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion did remove the warning and speed up the process!